# Running XSL Transformations oracle db, instead of java application

Tags: java, xml, performance, oracle, xslt

I have 3 tables in my db, which I am running XML processes on them.

1. XML Data
2. XML Recovery Data
3. Transformer (XSLTs to create XML Data from XML Recovery Data)

I am doing these steps on Java application side while retrieving data from these tables.

1. Retrieve XML Data.
2. If XML Data doesn't exist, search it's recovery in XML Recovery Data.
3. If XML Recovery found, find the corresponding XSLT from Transformers for the XML retrieved from Recovery table.
4. Transform Recovery XML with Transformer XSLT.
5. Insert the result to XML Data table.
6. Return XML Data.

As known parsing and transformation processes are high performance cost processes on Java applications. Also there is 4 db accesses in this scenario.

Is there any disadvantages of doing these processes all on Oracle DB side? 
Oracle uses a very native engine as XML parser which is written with C. And my db access will be only 1. But i am not sure costs of keeping some fields as XMLTYPE and disadvantages of this usage.

Comment: Just to mention, Oracle database has native Java support on server side. So it might be worth to consider just moving Java code to DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think doing it in oracle database will be more performance optimized. You have two options (Assuming you have Oracle 11g):

1) Either create a "static"  entry method of your java codebase and import that into oracle db using "loadjava".

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm

2) Use oracle in-built feature.

```
[XMLTYPE.TRANSFORM(myxml, myxsl)][2]
```